# Answer rate concern

Tags: discussion

I'm fairly new to this site but it seems to me there are a plethora of questions lacking an accepted answer that have one or more good answers available.

Should we perhaps pull together to remedy that, or does it not really matter?

Comment: My concern is more about people who are so eager to accept an answer that they accept the first one that comes along, usually within the first 2 hours of posting the question.

Comment: I can see why that would be damaging to the integrity of the site. Is that really a common problem?

Comment: @thanby yes it is, across the network.

Comment: And then there's questions with no upvote but several answers.  IF you feel compelled to answer a question, why was it not good enough to upvote it to?

Comment: That one I can definitely agree with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepting an answer is completely optional and up to the person who posted the question. All that the community can really control is whether or not there are good answers and that the best answer gets the most upvotes. The default view for users is to show the answers ordered by votes so if the best answer has the most upvotes than it doesn't matter to a passerby (our primary target audience) if the answer is accepted or not.

So what you can do about this is simple. Upvote the best answer. Don't pester someone to accept an answer, it's nice if they do, but we don't have all the details, maybe they haven't had a chance to try the solution, or maybe they think a better answer is still out there.

Comment: I've noticed that every possible statistic about these sites is scrutinized from several angles, and that the answer rate is actually factored in to the performance of Beta sites like this one (the main site at least). Is the answer rate in the Meta not important like it is in the main site? Or am I perhaps overestimating the importance of it in general?

Comment: The answer rate on A51 only factors *upvoted answers* not accepted answers. Having a low rate of accepted answers is not a concern, having a low rate of questions without an upvoted answer is a concern.

Comment: Ah I see how it works now, thanks for clearing that up.